# Css text color change not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a presentation for a site, and the background is black so I need the text to be white. The code to change the link colors is working, but the code to change the paragraphs is not. My knowledge of coding is what I have been able to teach myself, and I cannot find any errors in my code that could be causing this problem. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

This is my css:

```
body{background-color:#000000;}

p{color:#ffffff;
font: 12px arial;}

A {color:#7b0000; 
font:12px arial;
text-decoration:underline;
background:#transparent; 
border-style: solid; 
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px; 
border-color: Transparent;}
```

And this the html:

```
<body>
<div>
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<h2>Sub-heading One</h2>
<p>
Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 

Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 <a 

href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Test Link 1</a> Paragraph 1 

Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 Paragraph 1 
</p>
<h2>Sub-heading Two</h2>
<p>
Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 

Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 

Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 2 
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: used to small a in your css

Comment: Paragraph text is showing as white as u expected. http://jsbin.com/robugehi/2/

Comment: What color do you want paragraphs to be?

Comment: everything is fine check http://editor.livegap.com/?tid=bth9gkbxn0725

Comment: Here I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2mJ/2/, add the color to your body class, since you wanted everything on white.

Comment: Better use `body {color: white;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chucked your code into JSFiddle and it seems to work as you were explaining you wanted it to. The only text not displaying in white were the headers, which you can style using the following lines of css:

```
h1{color:white;}

h2{color:white;}
```

Check-out the JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QwK85/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me, just copied it and ran and the P tags apear in white just as expected.
Now do the same with your h1 and h2 tags

Answer (score 0):

Use `body{background-color:#000000; color:#fff;}` instead of `body{background-color:#000000;}` in you CSS part.